# .Net assembly copyright text shows question mark in diamond instead of (c) copyright character. How to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, .net-assembly

y solution contains a Visual Studio extension. It includes two projects whose assemblies are signed at build time, which is managed by a centralized build server.

When I right-click on the server-built assemblies for these two projects and view the "Details" tab, the copy right text shows: Copyright 
(?) CompanyName 2012. The "(?)" is a question mark inside a black diamond. It is supposed to be a copyright character, ©.

The other server-built assemblies in the solution do not have this issue. Also, the same exact assemblies built locally in the bin/Debug folders do not have this issue.

Why is the server-built version different? Appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the compiler used on the server isn't interpreting non-ASCII characters in the source code correctly. Visual Studio 2010's compiler, csc.exe, has a [/codepage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0kyekyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) parameter that you can use to specify the encoding. This is also available in [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as `CodePage`.

Comment: Thanks. What's confusing is the fact that other assemblies aren't affected by this when built by the server. It would seem that something in these two projects is causing the encoding to change there, but I can't seem to find it. Compiling it locally also doesn't yeild this (?) character, which would seem to suggest the project files are all good.

Comment: @DTran I suspect that the encoding on the source file is not set properly, or different than your other projects. You can check the encoding in an editor like Notepad++ or Notepad2.

Comment: Thank you so much Scott. For some unknown reason, the AssemblyInfo.cs file in these two projects had ANSI encoding. I changed them to UTF-8 and the copy right character appeared correctly in the server-built assembly properties.